# Wifi only works after turning the PC to standby (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, suspend, asus, atheros

I have a PC on which I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 in dual-boot with Windows 8.1. My problem is when I start the PC on Ubuntu, wifi doesn't work, but if I put my computer in standby then I get it out from standby, wifi works... My PC is the Asus X552C and my wifi card is the Atheros 9485.

Thank you per advance!

Comment: This guy appears to have a solution.. http://pkill-9.com/stabilizing-atheros-ar9485-ath9k-connection-linux-wheezy/ But What works for me is to disable and re-enable the Networking on the network manager applet...sometimes up to 3 times

Comment: None of this solutions works... :(

Comment: i have the same problem...create the above mentioned command where?

Comment: I have the same problem, but in my Dell xps 15, What can I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `/etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf` containing the line

```
options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1
```

and reboot....